# set inline style for dynamically created asp panel

Tags: c#, .net, css

I'm taking values from a database and dynamically placing points on a 2d cartesian plane. I need a way to set the top and left css properties.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Panel p = // dynamically created panel
p.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, ((int)yValue).ToString());
p.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, ((int)xValue).ToString());
```